# Editing a matrix in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, matrix

I am trying to obtain the first image, make some modification pixel by pixel and write the resultant to a second image.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    namedWindow("Frame");
    testVid("D:\\Penguins.mp4");
    destroyAllWindows();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void testVid(char* videoFilename)
{
    VideoCapture capture(videoFilename);
    Vec3b pixel;

    if (!capture.read(frame))
        return;
    Mat finalframe(frame.rows,frame.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < frame.rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < frame.cols; j++)
    {

        pixel = frame.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i));
        finalframe.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i)) = pixel;
    }

    imshow("Frame", finalframe);
    keyboard = waitKey(30);

    capture.release();
    getchar();
}
```

However, when I display second image using `imshow()` , A blank grey image is shown.

Now even if I do not choose to do any modifications, I face similar problems when I tried `second = first;`
The only thing that seems to work is `first.copyTo(second);`

Any reason why the second image refuses to do anything ??

Comment: How do you create `first` and `second`?

Comment: @Mailerdaimon first using imread() and second using Mat second(first.rows,first.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,255))

Comment: Looks ok. Can you post a short but complete code example showing the error?

Comment: @Mailerdaimon Complete code added. Here I am trying to copy a single frame of the video.

Comment: Displaying the original/loaded frame instead works?

Comment: Initializing with a colored cv::Scalar still gives you black display or chosen color?

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact not working code? 'keyboard' isnt declared anywhere.